# Bukkit - Why is it displaying null (using a config file)

Tags: plugins, null, minecraft, bukkit, inventory

So, I am making a custom plugin for my server, and one of my features requires me to set an integer in a gui that shows how many 'CommonPackages' a user has. The issue that I am having is that when I am getting the String from my config (My config uses a custom file creation/management class that was given to me by a friend) it is saying that it is null in the gui, I do not get any errors in the console, please may someone help me? The item in the gui and the code for setting the item in the gui.

[Item in the gui](https://gyazo.com/bd312aea1632943809f60605dd38b77a)

gui creation code:

```
public static Inventory WhiteBackpack(Player player) {

    UUID uuid = player.getUniqueId();
    Inventory inv = Bukkit.createInventory(null, 27, (inventoryname));

    ItemStack common = new ItemStack(Material.INK_SACK);
    common.setDurability((byte) 8);
    ItemMeta commonMeta = common.getItemMeta();
    commonMeta.setDisplayName(Utils.chat("&fCommon Packages &8» &f&l" + Main.pl.getFileControl().getConfig().getString("players." + uuid + ".Packages.Common"))); //How I access my custom configs.
    common.setItemMeta(commonMeta);

    inv.setItem(10, common);

    return inv;
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bukkit - Displaying null when getting a string from the config file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51233908/bukkit-displaying-null-when-getting-a-string-from-the-config-file)

Comment: Without seeing what is in the `getFileControl()` method or what is in your .yml file, it's impossible to figure out what is causing the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Without the code of your method to get the config I can only say that the string in the actual file is not present. 
As the Bukkit documentation states:
`If the String does not exist and no default value was specified, this will return null.`
So either the key just does not exist in the file or you pointed to the wrong file. The configuration should be well formated, too. (no tabs, only spaces)