# Bukkit - Displaying null when getting a string from the config file

Tags: plugins, config, minecraft, bukkit

So I've been working on a custom feature for my minecraft server, one of the things that I need to do is get an integer from the config file that is specific to each player to display how many Packages(keys) they have (Virtual items)

The issue that I am having is that in the GUI it is displaying 'null' instead of how many they have... Could anyone help me please?

[Item in the gui](https://gyazo.com/b8a164f3351746d9daa16733c817bca9)

Code for creating the player's instance in the config (Using a custom file class that was provided to me by a friend of mine.)

```
@EventHandler

public void playerJoin(PlayerJoinEvent event) {

    Main main = Main.getPlugin(Main.class);
    Player player = event.getPlayer();
    UUID uuid = player.getUniqueId();

    if (!main.getDataFolder().exists())
        main.getDataFolder().mkdirs();
    File file = new File(main.getDataFolder(), "players.yml");
    FileConfiguration config = YamlConfiguration.loadConfiguration(file);

    if (!config.contains("Users." + uuid + ".Username")) {

        try {

            System.out.println("Creating entry for " + player + " (" + uuid + ")");
            config.set("Users." + uuid + ".Username", player);
            config.set("Users." + uuid + ".Packages.Common", 0);
            config.set("Users." + uuid + ".Packages.Rare", 0);
            config.set("Users." + uuid + ".Packages.Epic", 0);
            config.set("Users." + uuid + ".Packages.Legendary", 0);
            config.set("Users." + uuid + ".Packages.Exotic", 0);
            config.save(file);
            System.out.println("Successfully created the  entry for " + " (" + uuid + ")");

        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
    }
}
```

Code for the creation of the item in the gui:

public static String inventoryname = Utils.chat("&fWhite Backpack");

public static Inventory WhiteBackpack(Player player) {

```
UUID uuid = player.getUniqueId();
Inventory inv = Bukkit.createInventory(null, 27, (inventoryname));

ItemStack common = new ItemStack(Material.INK_SACK);
common.setDurability((byte) 8);
ItemMeta commonMeta = common.getItemMeta();
commonMeta.setDisplayName(Utils.chat("&fCommon Packages &8» &f&l" + Main.pl.getFileControl().getConfig().getString("Users." + uuid + ".Packages.Common")));
common.setItemMeta(commonMeta);

inv.setItem(10, common);

return inv;
```

}

Comment: you seems to be saving to different config that reading... as on save you read some players.yml file but on read you just use some ` Main.pl.getFileControl().getConfig()`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bukkit How to change an int in the config file then be able to change it again without reloading (Custom config file class.))](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51250111/bukkit-how-to-change-an-int-in-the-config-file-then-be-able-to-change-it-again-w)

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple things wrong with your code.

**First**, you never account for what happens if the config you are loading does not exist. When you do `main.getDataFolder().mkdirs()`,  you account for if the folder is missing, but not the file.

**Second**, you are doing the following operation:

```
config.set("Users."  + uuid + ".Username", player);
```

This is incorrect because the `player` variable is of the type [`Player`](https://hub.spigotmc.org/javadocs/spigot/org/bukkit/entity/Player.html), not of the type [`String`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html). To fix this, you need to instead do the following:

```
config.set("Users." + uuid + ".Username", player.getName());
```

**Third**, you are attempting to write to a file that *might not exist*. When you initialize you file, you need to also make sure it exists, and if it does not, you need to create it. Right now you have the following:

```
File file = new File(main.getDataFolder(), "players.yml");
```

It must be changed to this block of code:

```
File file = new File(main.getDataFolder(), "players.yml");
if (!file.exists()) {
    try {
        file.createNewFile();
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

You could just have it be created when you attempt to save the file later on, but that is not ideal since it's safer to let Bukkit write to a file that already exists.

**Fourth**, and I'm not necessarily sure that this is a problem per se, but you are trying to access an [`Integer`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/?java/lang/Integer.html) value from the config file as if it were a [`String`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html). Try to replace the following:

```
commonMeta.setDisplayName(Utils.chat("&fCommon Packages &8» &f&l"
    + Main.pl.getFileControl().getConfig().getString("Users." + uuid + ".Packages.Common")));
```

with this instead:

```
commonMeta.setDisplayName(Utils.chat("&fCommon Packages &8» &f&l"
    + Main.pl.getFileControl().getConfig().getInt("Users." + uuid + ".Packages.Common")));
```

Hope this gets you moving in the right direction!